# Attempt to add link library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libconsole_bridge.so" to target "listener" which is not built in this directory

Tags: c++, cmake, ros

I got following error:

```
CMake Error at custom_msg/CMakeLists.txt:26 (target_link_libraries):
Attempt to add link library
"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libconsole_bridge.so" to target "listener" which
is not built in this directory.
```

**CMakeList.txt**

```
# %Tag(FULLTEXT)%
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(custom_msg)

## Find catkin and any catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_generation)

## Declare ROS messages and services
add_message_files(FILES Num.msg PoseVel.msg)
add_service_files(FILES AddTwoInts.srv)

## Generate added messages and services
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

## Declare a catkin package
catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime std_msgs)

## Build talker and listener
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(listener beginner_turorials_generate_messages_cpp)

# %EndTag(FULLTEXT)%
```

I have created two packages. The first package is named beginner_tutorials and the second one custom_msg. The beginner_tutorials was developed like described in the following link:
[Writing Publisher/Subscriber with C++](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)

After that I have created the new custom_msg package. I copied the CMakeList.txt, and the source code. I created a new msg named PoseVel.msg and changed the code in the Talker.cpp. In the package.xml I enabled message_generation and message_runtime.

My goal is to use my own custom message. I don't understand why the new package throws an error and the old one not. What's my mistake?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

> The named target must be created by add_library() within the project or as an IMPORTED library. If it is created within the project an ordering dependency will automatically be added in the build system to make sure the named library target is up-to-date before the  links.

From [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/target_link_libraries.html?highlight=i)